# Appending GSP element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, grails

As titled

Maybe this has been asked before but i couldn't find it. Maybe i was using wrong search keywords..

I'm trying to append child form into a GSP form. The main form is as follows

```
<div>
    ------------ CHUNK OF INPUT CODES HERE -----------------
    <button id="addRow">Add Another Row</button>
    <div id="childForm">
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea here is to append a subform (which is a separate GSP template) inside the childForm block. The subform will be appended at the bottom of the existing subform (if any) by pressing the "Add Another Row" button, and will keep appending as long as the button is pressed.

So how to append the subform in such way using JQuery?

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$("#childForm").append("<div class='subaccordion'><g:render id='subForm' template='subForm'/></div>");
```

Any other possible idea with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addRow').click(function(){
$("#childForm").append("<div class='subaccordion'><g:render id='subForm' template='subForm'/></div>");
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/77gyoazs/

Comment: That's what i tried too... but it won't work because of g:render rendering the template straight inside the script. I think the error message displayed was illegal token.